# Why was this question closed as "off topic"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Why was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846976/sending-ping-output-to-a-variable) closed as "off topic"?

I see that there are some issues with this post, e.g. the formatting (Anthon [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1866284)/[edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15846976/2) it, not correctly through), grammar/capitalization.

But otherwise it looks like a valid question to me. It is neither too localized, although the OP tagged it as [router](/questions/tagged/router) and said that he uses it on his router, but this is not relevant for this question.
It is also a programming question (How to accomplish a certain task in a specific programming language).

The code is valid and works everywhere with a `ping` command and Tcl without the `'` (the OP used them to mark code, which was not edited out).

So why was this question considered to be "off topic"?

Comment: "(How to accomplish a certain task in a specific language)" What language might that be? I believe answering that alone by editing the question accordingly will help it get reopened.

Comment: It's Tcl. mhh, programming language would be better.. edit.

Comment: The question has been reopened...  It would be nice to know why it was closed in the first place though.

Comment: Every time I see a Meta post about a closure containing a sentence like "I see that there are some issues with this post" I die a little inside. Why, oh why didn't you fix the issues you've identified before you post on Meta?

Comment: @Yannis Because I could/should not. Minor edits, frowned upon as suggested edits.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yeah I noticed your SO rep after I posted the comment (which was more of a general rant). Nevertheless a lot of eyes will see the question right after you post about it on Meta. I'd say you should go ahead and fix everything you can fix right before you submit your Meta question. This way everyone who'll go to check it out will notice the pending edit and it'll probably get approved in seconds. Especially if you add something like "trying to bring the question to the best shape possible before asking about it on Meta" in the edit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this was just a mistake that was compounded by the review queues. It's reopened now, nothing to worry about.

In the future, if you see a post which you feel is wrongly closed, do some of the following:

- Edit it to make it clearer that it is not a dupe/a precise question/on topic/etc
- Flag, asking for a reopen, stating reasons
- Come to meta, like you did here :)

Comment: I prefer asking on meta instead of flagging it. Only diamond mods can see custom flags, but such things could be handled by the community itself, so no need for flagging imho.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: Sure, that works. I personally would flag first and escalate if it didn't work.